# echo only value name no all in array

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, multi-upload

i want echo only value name no all.

my array:

```
$file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                            'height' => $imageVar->height,
                            'width' => $imageVar->width
                            );
                }
```

my foreach:

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    echo '<li><ul>';
    foreach ($file as $item => $value) {
        echo '<li>'.$item.': '.$value.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
 }
```

output now:

> - name: Chrysanthemum19.jpg
>   file:
>     D:/xampp/htdocs/Siran-mehdi/uploads/Chrysanthemum19.jpg
>    size:
>     858.78
>    ext: .jpg
>    image_type: jpeg
>    height: 768
>     width:    1024
> - name: Desert19.jpg
>    file: D:/xampp/htdocs/Siran-mehdi/uploads/Desert19.jpg
>    size: 826.11
>    
>     ext: .jpg
>    image_type: jpeg
>    height: 768
>    width: 1024

i want this output:

> Chrysanthemum19.jpg, Desert19.jpg

see you full class and Controller
[class Multi_upload(libraries)](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/multiupload.txt) [CI_Controller](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/upload.txt)

With respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find the part of your loop that outputs the filename:

```
echo '<li>'.$item.': '.$value.'</li>';
```

You only want the value to be displayed when `$item` is equal to 'name'. You can express that in code like this:

```
$file['name']
```

Then, eliminate all the parts of your code that do not contribute to the desired output. Your new code can look like this:

```
$output = array();

foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    $output[] = $file['name'];
}

echo implode( ',' $output );
```

Comment: if i want store in database with use of function serialize, how is it?

Comment: @Mehd S: You can store the single string ('Chrysanthemum19.jpg, Desert19.jpg') in the database as-is with no modification. If you wish to insert the filenames a separate rows in the database, you can place your insert statement within the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: i use of array data <input name="img[]">, for store(save-insert) in database i want use of function serialize.

Comment: Sounds like more detail is needed on that unrelated question. Can you open a new question to address that topic?

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array();
foreach ($file_list as $file) {
  $names[] = $file['name'];
}
echo implode(',', $names);
```

Using PHP5.3 you can compact it a little bit more

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function ($file) {
  return $file['name'];
}, $file_list);
```

But there is no semantic difference between both.

Comment: This one is exact output of request.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing all file information data. You want to print only name of it. Here:

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    echo '<li>' . $file->name . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    echo '<li><ul>';
    foreach ($file as $item => $value) {
        if ($item == 'name'){
             echo '<li>'.$item.': '.$value.'</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
 }
```

Tjeu

Comment: A better way would be as Berk said

    foreach($upload_data as $file) {
        echo '<li>' . $file->name . '</li>';
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    echo '<li><ul>',$file['name'],'</ul></li>';
 }
```

Comment: if i want store in database with use of function serialize, how is it?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    foreach ($file as $item) {
        $return[] = $file['name'];
    }
}
echo implode(",",$return);
$to_store_in_db = serialize($return);
```

**Adding serialize**

Comment: if i want store in database with use of function serialize, how is it?